# xslt - convert ANY xml to a table

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I'm trying to create a generic XSLT file that will handle any xml input as such I don't want to be referring to specific child nodes in the xslt as the xml could be anything. I don't expect the xml to have a hierarchy any deeper than 10 child nodes.

sample xml:

```
   <Client>
      <LastName>Bill</LastName>
      <FirstName>Gates</FirstName>
      <MiddleName/>
      <Suffix/>
      <DateOfBirth>30-May-1968</DateOfBirth>
      <PlaceOfBirth/>
      <SSN>n/a</SSN>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <District>
        <City>SHELTON</City>
        <Mayor>wong</Mayor>
      </District>
      <State>WA</State>
      <Zip>96484</Zip>
   </Client>
   <Client>
      <LastName>Warron</LastName>
      <FirstName>Buffet</FirstName>
      <MiddleName>P</MiddleName>
      <Suffix/>
      <DateOfBirth>12-Aug-1957</DateOfBirth>
      <PlaceOfBirth>Mississippi</PlaceOfBirth>
      <SSN>n/a</SSN>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <City>Missi</City>
      <State>KS</State>
      <Account>
        <Type>
        <Name>Cash</Name>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        </Type>
      </Account>
      <Zip>66096</Zip>
   </Client>
```

xslt so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
 xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" > 

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Workbook>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*">
  <Worksheet>
  <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name(/*/*)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
    <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
      <Row>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[position() = 1]/*">
          <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
          </Data></Cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Row>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <Row>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Row>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
  <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Data></Cell>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use this VBA macro to do pull it all together:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sourceFile As String
Dim xlstFile As String
Dim exportFile As String
Dim filePath As String

filePath = Application.ThisWorkbook.path

sourceFile = filePath & "\client.xml"
xlstFile = filePath & "\trans.xml"
exportFile = filePath & "\export1.xls"

Transform sourceFile, xlstFile, exportFile
End Sub
Private Sub Transform(sourceFile, stylesheetFile, resultFile)

Dim source As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim stylesheet As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Dim result As New MSXML2.DOMDocument30

' Load data.
source.async = False
source.Load sourceFile

' Load style sheet.
stylesheet.async = False
stylesheet.Load stylesheetFile

If (source.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0) Then
   MsgBox ("Error loading source document: " & source.parseError.reason)
   Else
If (stylesheet.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0) Then
      MsgBox ("Error loading stylesheet document: " & stylesheet.parseError.reason)
   Else
      ' Do the transform.
      source.transformNodeToObject stylesheet, result
      result.Save resultFile
End If
End If

End Sub
```

desired output (something similar to this):

```
LastName    FirstName   MiddleName  Suffix  DateOfBirth PlaceOfBirth    SSN Gender  District    State   Zip
Bill    Gates           30-May-1968     n/a Male     SHELTON wong    WA 96484
Warron  Buffet  P       12-Aug-1957 Mississippi n/a Male    Missi   KS  66096
Steev   Jobbs           19-Apr-1959 Cupertino   n/a Male    Cupertino   CA  96066
```

If one of the xmls does not have a certain tag just display a blank cell in the table. Order of the tags as column headers is not important. At the moment the xslt is not handling xmls with different structure.

Comment: Question is what do I need to change in the xslt so that it gives me the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to convert ANY xml to a table, then you can do it, but it won't be a very pretty table. (Some of the relational databases that support XML have an operation called "shredding" that attempts to do this.) You certainly can't do it by taking a stylesheet that works with trivial XML and then try to generalise it.